# How would I make a post on the users wall extending this example?

Tags: javascript, facebook, cordova, oauth

I am making an app with phonegap, adobe build and using facebook for authentication with this snippet of code.

I am looking to handle the 'success' login with some form of callback I suppose, and make a post on the user's wall.

```
       <script type="text/javascript">
       var my_client_id = "133914256793487", // YOUR APP ID
    my_secret = "862f10f883f8d91617b77b4b143abc8d", // YOUR APP SECRET 
    my_redirect_uri = "https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html", // LEAVE THIS
    my_type ="user_agent", my_display = "touch"; // LEAVE THIS

var facebook_token = "fbToken"; // OUR TOKEN KEEPER
var ref; //IN APP BROWSER REFERENCE

// FACEBOOK
var Facebook = {
    init:function(){
         // Begin Authorization
         alert("we have begun");
         var authorize_url = "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?";
         authorize_url += "client_id=" + my_client_id;
         authorize_url += "&redirect_uri=" + my_redirect_uri;
         authorize_url += "&display=" + my_display;
         authorize_url += "&scope=publish_stream";

             //CALL IN APP BROWSER WITH THE LINK
         ref = window.open(authorize_url, '_blank', 'location=no');

         ref.addEventListener('loadstart', function(event){

             Facebook.facebookLocChanged(event.url);

          });
         } , 
    facebookLocChanged:function(loc){
        if (loc.indexOf("https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html") >= 0 ) {

            //CLOSE INAPPBROWSER AND NAVIGATE TO INDEX
            ref.close();

            //THIS IS MEANT TO BE DONE ON SERVER SIDE TO PROTECT CLIENT SECRET
            var codeUrl = 'https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id='+my_client_id+'&client_secret='+my_secret+'&redirect_uri='+my_redirect_uri+'&code='+loc.split("=")[1];
            console.log('CODE_URL::' + codeUrl);
            $.ajax({
                url: codeUrl,
                data: {},
                type: 'POST',
                async: false,
                cache: false,
                success: function(data, status){
                    //WE STORE THE TOKEN HERE
                    localStorage.setItem(facebook_token, data.split('=')[1].split('&')[0]);
                    },
                error: function(){
                    alert("Unknown error Occured");
                }
            }); 
        }
    }
     }  
       </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
           Facebook.init();
            </script>
```

Can anybody advise how to appropriately extend this example - and where I can find the API to be able to help myself? Currently it successfully asks the user to login - facebook pops up - I successfully accept and then it returns with Success - and a red message saying the user should retain this URL securely.

Cheers,

Andy

Answer (score 0):

I know that changing the whole structure of your code is a bit of a daunting task, but I highly recommend using [PhoneGap Facebook Plugin](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-facebook-plugin). And since you're using build, you can also easily integreate the [Facebook Connect plugin](https://build.phonegap.com/docs/plugins#facebookconnect) from Build.

I highly recommend you check out the following two files found within the `phonegap-facebook-plugin / example / HackBook` folder of the [PhoneGap Facebook plugin repository](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-facebook-plugin): [index.html](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-facebook-plugin/blob/master/example/HackBook/index.html) and [js/auth.js](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-facebook-plugin/blob/master/example/HackBook/js/auth.js) .

When using the javascript FB Api, you can specify a callback function as the first parameter, as in `FB.login(function(response) { ... });` You can find an example in the [docs](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/).

Line 25 of auth.js shows an example of making a call to the FB API, using the following code `FB.api('/me' ...`. While this code requests information about the logged in user, you can make any javascript API call with `FB.api()`, which you can learn about [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.api/) (look at the fourth example).

Check out the code and see how it works/how it's implemented, and let me know if you have any questions :)

Comment: Hey, I actually wanted to use that - but ran into difficulties. Perhaps you can cast your eye over my related post : http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/16474374/facebookconnect-plugin-with-phonegap-adobe-build-not-working

Comment: What version of cordova are you using? and were you testing the binary app or just the unbuilt code?

Comment: Using phonegap version 2.3.0 and testing with the binary app built with phonegap adobe build - how would I test without the binary!